# How do I run Open MPI jobs on two VMs?

Tags: linux, openmpi

I'm trying to run the `hello_ompi` program on two Ubuntu virtual machines on my computer.
This program can be found [here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world).

The VMs have two processors and one core per processor.
The installed OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3-LTS 64 bit.

The hostfile I'm using is as follows:

```
192.168.xxx.xxx
192.168.xxx.xxx
```

I tried:

```
mpirun -n 2 --hostfile my_hostfile hello_ompi
```

The ouptut was:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       192.168.xxx.xxx
Executable: hello_ompi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to replace with `./hello_ompi` in your command above (add `./`)? PWD is most probably not in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the executable needs to be in a directory that is identical to that of the host node.
i.e. if on the host node path to the executable is:

```
/home/youruser/somedir/executable.c
```

Then on all of the machines in the hostfile the executable must be in the exact same directory on those machines.

The command ran perfectly once I corrected this.